# A little help on mathematical notation and on the definition of a manifold

Tags: general-topology, notation

I was going through the mathematical definition of manifold and it defined it as follow :

" A topological space, $\ M $ is an n-dimensional real manifold if there is a family of subsets $\ U _\alpha $  , $\ \alpha $ $\ \epsilon $$\ A $ , of $\ \Re ^n $, and a quotient map$\ f$ : $\ \coprod_\alpha $$\ U_\alpha$ $\ \to$ $\ M $ such that $\ f$|$\ U_\alpha$ is a homeomorphism onto the image and for all 
$\ \alpha$ ."

What does the notion $\ f$|$\ U_\alpha$ mean ? I suppose it means $\ f $ being confined to $\ U_\alpha$ . Am I right ?

What is the significance of taking the indexing set $\ A $ here ?

Comment: I would have expected $f$ to be restricted to a single $U_\alpha$. It's kind of strange to restrict a function to its own domain...

Comment: @nelv : So , does that notion mean what I expected ?

Comment: I don't understand what's the difference between $f$ and $f|\Pi_\alpha U_\alpha$. Also, what do you mean with "confined to $\Pi_\alpha U_\alpha$? Confined from where?

Comment: This is the first time I see this definition. Does $\Pi_\alpha U_\alpha$ mean the cartesian product of all the open set $U_\alpha$? Suppose that $\alpha=1,2$ and $U_1,U_2$ is a two chart covering of the sphere. How could be defined $f$?

Answer (score 1):

There are several typos which make this question confusing: Not $\prod_{\alpha} U_\alpha$ but $\coprod_{\alpha} U_\alpha$, the disjoint union of the sets $U_\alpha$. Secondly, it is $f|U_\alpha$, not $f|\prod_{\alpha} U_\alpha$. Thirdly, an important assumption is missing: Each $U_\alpha$ is an open subset of $R^n$. With this in mind, $f|U_\alpha$ is just the restriction of $f$ to $U_\alpha$. The set $A$ is just for bookkeeping, to indicate that each set $U_\alpha$ has its own index and to differentiate between different sets $U_\alpha$.

Just for the record: One commonly assumes that manifolds are Hausdorff, your definition does not make this assumption and allows for non-Hausdorff manifolds. My guess is that this is another missing assumption.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out . So ,what  does f|$\ U_\alpha $ mean ?

Comment: $f$ is a function, $U_\alpha$ is a subset of the domain of $f$, and $f | U_\alpha$ is the function obtained by restricting the domain of $f$ to the subset $U_\alpha$.